# Azure Data Factory sftp copy creates empty files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a DataFactory which is supposed to copy files from an ntfs share to an sftp.

For this I used a "Copy Data" block:

[image]

This block is executed within a foreach which performs the copy for a collection of source folders, so @item().Source is used as part of the WildCard Path

For the sink I have the following settings:

[image]

This works, but sometimes it just creates empty files on the destination and the source files are deleted anyway.

This pipeline is triggered on a schedule, so I could imagine a new run being started while the other is still running.

I have no errors however, and the deletion of source files after an incorrect copy is just terrible behaviour.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Is there a way to make this work reliably?

Comment: Are you using an self-hosted integration runtime for copying the files? And if so, what version?

Comment: Hello, I am indeed using a self-hosted integration runtime, the version of which is 5.8.7875.2.

Comment: @Koen I am, and my feeling is that the ADF managed network feature and its managed runtime, which is in preview, somehow ignores that my copy sink is non-hierarchical (Gen1), regardless of what the source is (Gen2), causing oddities around empty files and the like. That has a number of other applications, such as Databricks, unable to read files off the mounted sink, even if the data is there. Running the copy via the standard Azure IR gives no issue. Again more of a feeling, it could be different or unrelated issues stapling up, but your precise question got me triggered :) Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if the "Upload with temp file" feature on the Sink side of the Copy Data activity is working on the SFTP side.

[image: information from UI about not supporting SFTP server]

However, we would expect to receive an error if this was the case.

Depending on how reliable you want your solution to be, I would stop deleting the files before another process checks that the data is correctly transferred. You could do this by calculating the NTFS source file checksums and the SFTP destination checksum. If they match up, you can safely remove the file on the NTFS side.

Comment: I think that renaming the tempfiles is not a problem for the SFTP server since this works most of the time. I like your suggestion of comparing the checksums, but I'm not sure if  this will be easy to implement in a data factory pipeline. (It's a shame that the copy activity is not more robust)